# Google analytics get custom report from api call

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am very new to this google analytics thing.
I have 3 things.

1. A RESTapi written using node.js express framework.
2. A mobile app written using react native
3. A admin panel UI written using vue.js

Mobile app is a food app. It has so many restaurants.
I want to pass a restaurant_id and need to get the dish views for that specific restaurant only.

for that I have to make a API call from my admin panel UI.
According to official docs I have to make my api call like this.

```
function makeApiCall() {
  var apiQuery = gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
    'ids': TABLE_ID,
    'start-date': '2010-01-01',
    'end-date': '2010-01-15',
    'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
    'dimensions': 'ga:source,ga:keyword',
    'sort': '-ga:sessions,ga:source',
    'filters': 'ga:medium==organic',
    'max-results': 25
  });
  // ...
}
```

To pass a such `TABLE_ID`, how do I create a table in my analytics? 
As well as `start-date` and `end-date` are parameters I guess.
How do I create such params along with that `TABLE`?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the sentence in the documentation that precedes the code example you will see that TABLE_ID refers to the view id:

[image]

The easiest way to get the view id is to navigate in the admin section to the "view settings" (first item in the rightmost column). You will find the view id in the "Basic settings" section.